# Multiple router-outlets

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have two router-outlets, one in the app-component.html as root outlet ad another in MarketComponent.

```
//app.component.html
<router-outlet (activate)="activatedComponent($event)" (deactivate)="deactivatedComponent($event)"></router-outlet>

// Market.component.html
<div class="container12">

  <button class="btn-1" 
          [routerLink]="[{outlets: {subout: ''}}]" 
          [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
          <span>Assessment</span>
  </button>

  <button class="btn-1" 
          [routerLink]="[{outlets: {subout: 'counselling'}}]"
          [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
          <span>Counselling</span>
  </button>

  <button class="btn-1"
          [routerLink]="[{outlets: {subout: 'webinar'}}]"
          [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
          <span>Webinar</span>
  </button>

<button class="btn-1"
        [routerLink]="['productDetails', {product: 'Career Wizard'}]"
        [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <span>CAreer Wiard</span>
</button>

  <!-- View for market components will go here. -->
  <router-outlet name="subout"></router-outlet>

</div>

//app.module.ts
{
        path: 'market',
        component: MarketComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'productDetails',   component: DetailedDescriptionComponent},
            { path: 'counselling',      component: MarketCounsellingComponent, outlet: 'subout'},
            { path: 'webinar',          component: MarketWebinarComponent, outlet: 'subout' },
            { path: '',                 component: MarketAssessmentComponent, outlet: 'subout'},
            { path: '**',               redirectTo: 'erroror' }
        ]
    }
```

**Desired Functionality:**  if i visit '**market/counselling', 'market/webinar', 'market/'**,these should be rendered inside MarketComponent.This is working fine.

However, i want to display/render the ProductDetailComponent component **('market/productDetails')** in the root router-outlet i.e in my **app.component.html's router-outlet** and not in my MarketComponent's outlet. But its not being rendered. When i click on the **4th button ie. Career Wizard**, the url is getting changed, but the component is not getting instantiated/rendered.
I thought if i give root's router-outlet a name, then it may work.So i did this.

```
//app.component.html
<router-outlet name="primary" (activate)="activatedComponent($event)" (deactivate)="deactivatedComponent($event)"></router-outlet>

//MarketComponent.html
<button class="btn-1"
        [routerLink]="[{outlets: {primary: ['productDetails', {product: 'Career Wizard'}]}}]"
        [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <span>CAreer Wiard</span>
</button>

//app.modules.ts
{
        path: 'market',
        component: MarketComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'productDetails',   component: DetailedDescriptionComponent, outlet: 'primary'},
            { path: 'counselling',      component: MarketCounsellingComponent, outlet: 'subout'},
            { path: 'webinar',          component: MarketWebinarComponent, outlet: 'subout' },
            { path: '',                 component: MarketAssessmentComponent, outlet: 'subout'},
            { path: '**',               redirectTo: 'erroror' }
        ]
    }
```

But this is also not working. The url is getting changed but not routing is being done.
Any idea why its happening so?

Comment: you need to define separate route for your market/product details route

Comment: If you want to display the `DetailedDescriptionComponent` in the root `router-outlet` you can't have it as a child of the market path. It needs to be a root level path.

Comment: @AamirKhan thanks that worked.